# Almost sure convergence of recursively defined Random Variables

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, recurrence-relations, almost-everywhere

I have a sequence of Random variables that is recursively defined in the following way
$$ Y_t = 1 + |Z_{t-1}|Y_{t-1} $$
Here the $Z_t$ are i.i.d. standard normal random variables.
I need to show almost sure convergence of the sequence $Y_t$. I have managed to show convergence in mean by taking expectations on both sides and finding
$$\lim_{t \rightarrow \infty} E[Y_t] = \frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{\sqrt{\pi}-\sqrt{2}}$$
Can I take the same approach by taking limits to conclude
$$ Y_t \rightarrow \frac{1}{1-|Z|}=Y \quad \text{a.s.}$$
Where $Z$ a standard normal R.V.? Or does this need a more sophisticated argument, i.e. I've tried showing $\sum E|Y_t -Y| <\infty$, but couldn't finish the argument

Comment: Not sure the almost sure convergence exists. In fact, luckily $E(|Z|) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} <1$ then the convergence in mean exists. But in the case of convergence a.s, $|Z|$ isn't bounded by 1.

Comment: I was also not sure how to deal with the case $|Z|=1$, I figured since this is a probability 0 event it might not "matter" much?

Comment: For the convergence in mean, you used the property that $E(|Z|)<1$ so that the limit exists. But I don't think you can use this property for the convergence a.s. This property should be modified to, for example, $|Z_n|<K<1  \text{a.s}$. But even with this additional assumption, I don't know you can have the convergence a.s. $$$$
Besides, concerning your comment above, not only the case $|Z|=1$ but also the case $|Z|>1$ which is a non-null probaiblity event.

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried proving something that was not necessary for solving the greater question at hand. Nevertheless, it was an interesting question and helpful to refresh this knowledge and learn more than what was needed :).

Comment: What is $Y_1$ (or $Y_0$?)

Comment: @PhoemueX The OP doesn't define $Y_1$ or $Y_0$ but IMO, even if $Y_1, Y_0$ are constant or $0$, I still believe there is no convergence.

Comment: The variance also converges https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/435049/variance-of-z-x-1-x-1-x-2-x-1-x-2-x-3-cdots

Comment: Note: "Convergence in mean" (i.e., $\mathbb{E} |Y_t - Y| \to 0$) is not the same as convergence of the expectations (i.e., $\mathbb{E} Y_t \to \mathbb{E} Y$)!

Comment: Thank you for the comment about convergence in mean, indeed this is convergence in expectation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sequence **never** converges almost everywhere.
The proof proceeds in a number of steps.

**Step 1:** We show by induction that
$$
  Y_{t+1} \geq 1 + |Z_t| + |Z_t \cdots Z_1| \, Y_1
  \qquad \forall \, t \in \mathbb{N}_{\geq 2} .
$$
Indeed, for $t = 2$, we have
\begin{align*}
  Y_{t+1}
  & = 1 + |Z_t| \, Y_t \\
  & = 1 + |Z_2| \, Y_2 \\
  & = 1 + |Z_2| (1 + |Z_1| \, Y_1) \\
  & \geq 1 + |Z_2| + |Z_2 Z_1| \, Y_1 ,
\end{align*}
as claimed.
Next, if the claim holds for some $t \geq 2$, we see
\begin{align*}
  Y_{t+2}
  & = 1 + |Z_{t+1}| \, Y_{t+1} \\
  & \geq 1 + |Z_{t+1}| (1 + |Z_t| + |Z_t\cdots Z_1| \, Y_1) \\
  & \geq 1 + |Z_{t+1}| + |Z_{t+1}\cdots Z_1| \, Y_1 .
\end{align*}

**Step 2:**
We show that $V_t := |Z_t \cdots Z_1| \, Y_1 \to 0$ almost surely.
Since $Y_1$ is a real-valued random variable, it suffices to show
$|Z_t \cdots Z_1| \to 0$ almost surely.
But it is well-known that $\mathbb{E} |Z_t| = \sqrt{2/\pi} =: \theta < 1$.
By monotone convergence and independence, we thus see
$$
  \mathbb{E} \sum_{t=1}^\infty |Z_t \cdots Z_1|
  = \sum_{t=1}^\infty \mathbb{E} |Z_t \cdots Z_1|
  = \sum_{t=1}^\infty \theta^n
  < \infty,
$$
by convergence of the geometric series.
This shows $\sum_{t=1}^\infty |Z_t \cdots Z_1| < \infty$ almost surely.

**Step 3:** In this step we complete the proof.
Assume towards a contradiction that $Y_t \to Y$ almost surely.
Then $Y_{t+1} - V_t \to Y$ almost surely.
Since convergence sequences are bounded and since Step 1 shows
$0 \leq |Z_t| \leq 1 + |Z_t| \leq Y_{t+1} - V_t \to Y$,
this implies that $Z^\ast := \sup_t |Z_t| < \infty$ almost surely.

However, since the random variables $Z_t$ are i.i.d. standard normally distributed,
the [second Borel-Cantelli Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma#Converse_result)
shows for arbitrary $M \in \mathbb{N}$ that the event $F_M := \{ |Z_t| \geq M \text{ infinitely often} \}$
has probability one.
This easily implies $Z^\ast = \infty$ almost surely,
which is the desired contradiction.